# Cyanogenmod wants a firmware update every time I connect USB

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, firmware, lg

So the title pretty much says it all and it's a pretty weird problem. Every time I connect my cyanogenmod via USB to my computer it reboots and wants a firmware update. As far as I can tell, this started happening while I was developing an app. I was using android-studio to run it on my phone when gnome started having problems mounting it.

It shouldn't have been mounting it to begin with because the phone was only connected for usb-debugging. However, because gnome was having problems, it kept trying to mount the phone and I was getting mount notifications every couple of seconds. Because this was so annoying, I disabled auto-mount in the dconf-editor in gnome. The notifications stopped, but at that point, android-studio was also not able to install the app on the phone anymore. Then at some point, the phone "crashed" and restarted, asking me for a firmware update.

I can restart the phone into normal mode by disconnecting the USB cord and holding the power button. Then everything works fine, but still every time I connect the phone to USB, it reboots, wanting a firmware update. I've tried doing `adb devices` while the phone is in the firmware screen, but `adb` doesn't find my phone, so I can't even debug like that.

Is there a way to debug or fix this? Or is there a way cancel the firmware update from the firmware screen, so that it won't interpret a usb-connection as a signal to do a firmware update? BTW, the phone is an LG G2, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

So I've researched this a little further and found the answer [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-lg-g2/392033-firmware-update-has-my-lgg2-frozen.html#post4506395). This seems to have been a side effect of not having enough space left on the device. It would be cooler if they had said something to that effect, but at least the problem is solved